# Why after marshalling, just one element of the array contains a value?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm calling a c++ function from my c# code. And i'm using marshalling, but when returned from c++ code, in my c# code just one element is filled of this array.

My C++ struct:

```
typedef struct DEV_SUB_STATE_ITEM_s
{
char err_text[NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
uint32_t state;
char obj_name[NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
char name[NAME_MAX_LENGTH];
} DEV_SUB_STATE_ITEM_t;
```

My struct in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct DEVICE_Sub_State_Item
{
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
public String err_text;
public UInt32 state;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
public String obj_name;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]
public String name;
}
```

My function prototype in C++:

```
int COMSpClient::GetSubSlotList (UINT32 obj_rid, DEV_SUB_STATE_ITEM_t** subSlotItems);
```

My function prototype in C#:

```
[DllImport(@"xxx_OMSpClient.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "?OMSpClient_GetSubSlotList@@YAHPAXHPAPAUDEV_SUB_STATE_ITEM_s@@@Z", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static unsafe extern Int32 GetSubSlotList(Int32 p_hHandle, UInt32 obj_rid,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] ref DEVICE_Sub_State_Item[] sub_slot_items);
```

My usage in C#:

```
OMSpClientWrapper.DEVICE_Sub_State_Item[] sub_slots = new      OMSpClientWrapper.DEVICE_Sub_State_Item[5];
// TODO : load subordinate list!!!
OMSpClientWrapper.GetSubSlotList(this.omsp_client_handle, MyDevice.DeviceRID, ref sub_slots);
```

Comment: The word "list" in the function name is troublesome, doesn't look like it is actually returning a list.  If it returns an array then the basic question is: how does the client code know how many elements are in the array?  The pinvoke marshaller of course doesn't know, it can only return one element.

Comment: i'm sure its returning a list.

Comment: Then the structure should contain a field that's a pointer to the next element in the list.  It doesn't.  Post C++ code that shows how this function is getting called.

Comment: yes, but this function is returning an array that is array of struct. So it isn't necessary a pointer for the next element.

Comment: i fixed my problem. everyone find this solution in below link: http://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/example-custom-marshaler-the-array-marshaler/

Comment: Hmm, no, that talks about the simple case of the function explicitly returning the array size through an int*.  Trivially done with SizeParamIndex.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly awkward function to marshal. The unmanaged code allocates the array and returns a pointer to the array to the caller. Hence the double pointer in the signature. You cannot marshal that automatically using p/invoke.

You will need to use an `IntPtr`, passed as an `out` parameter, and then do the rest of the marshalling yourself.

```
[DllImport(...)]
public static extern int GetSubSlotList(
    IntPtr p_hHandle, 
    uint obj_rid, 
    out IntPtr sub_slot_items
);
```

At this point, `sub_slot_items` points to the first element of the array. You'll then need to use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` to read out each item, incrementing the point as you go.

And you'll likely need to call back into the unmanaged code to ask it to deallocate the memory.

Of course, this is messy. If you have control over the interface a better design would be to let the caller allocate the array. The code would look like this:

```
int COMSpClient::GetSubSlotList(
    UINT32 obj_rid, 
    DEV_SUB_STATE_ITEM_t subSlotItems[]
);
```

You'd also presumably want to pass the length of the array unless there is some other reason for it to be well known by both sides.

On the C# side the code would be:

```
[DllImport(...)]
public static extern int GetSubSlotList(
    IntPtr p_hHandle, 
    uint obj_rid, 
    [Out] DEVICE_Sub_State_Item[] sub_slot_items
);
```

Comment: but i will use [out] parameter in c#, so i may use **subSlotItems. because pointer to array?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand that comment.

Comment: i'm using out parameter sub_slot_items in c# but in c++ code i'n not using a output parameter just an array on your solution. İs it right?

Answer (score 0):

Marshalling to a string is infinitely more annoying than it initially looks. It would perhaps be easier to marshal your strings into a fixed byte buffer, and then constructing the string like so:

```
public unsafe struct DEVICE_Sub_State_Item
{
    public fixed byte err_text[50];
    public UInt32 state;
    public fixed byte obj_name[50];
    public fixed byte name[50];

    public string ErrorText
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[50];

            fixed (byte* b = err_text)
                Marshal.Copy(new IntPtr(b), buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Where your actual error text would be kept as a pointer in the struct, and it is only properly read and converted to a string when you call the `ErrorText`property on it.

You will need to enable unsafe code under the project's build options if you decide to go about it this way though.